# Actionscript 3 TextField Scroll

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll

I want to allow the user to scroll a TextField. Everything works fine, except for the scrolling- it doesn't happen.  Here's the code:

```
format.size = fontSize;
format.font = font;
format.color = color;   
linerNotesText.defaultTextFormat = format;

linerNotesText.wordWrap = true;
linerNotesText.multiline = true;
linerNotesText.background = true;
linerNotesText.backgroundColor = backColor;

linerNotesText.text = text;

linerNotesText.x = x;
linerNotesText.y = y;
linerNotesText.width = width;
linerNotesText.height = height;

linerNotesText.scrollV = 4;  // did this to see if it was really set to 4, it was not
linerNotesText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, TextMouseClickHandler);
addChild(linerNotesText);


private function TextMouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    linerNotesText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, TextMouseMoveHandler);
}
private function TextMouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (linerNotesText.mouseY > e.target.y + e.target.height / 2)
        linerNotesText.scrollV++;
    else
        linerNotesText.scrollV--;
    trace("V position = ", linerNotesText.scrollV);
}
```

The V position is always 1.  I notice that maxScrollV is also 1.  bottonScrollV is 5, which is correct- there are 5 lines.  scaleX, scaleY, and scaleX are 1, but scrollRect is null.  Is that where the problem is?

Comment: Just looked up scrollRect, that's not the answer...

Answer (score 0):

That turned out to be simple, although I'm not sure why the documentation points to the wrong place.  All I had to do was change:

```
if (linerNotesText.mouseY > e.target.y + e.target.height / 2)
        linerNotesText.scrollV++;
    else
        linerNotesText.scrollV--;
```

into:

```
if (linerNotesText.mouseY > e.target.y + e.target.height / 2)
        linerNotesText.y++;
    else
        linerNotesText.y--;
```

and it works.